# Python __getattribute__ fallbacks to __getattr__

Tags: python

I have a situation, where **getattribute** fallbacks to **getattr** and then again **getattribute** gets called.

How current **getattribute** gets called again? I am confused.

```
class Count(object):

    def __init__(self,mymin,mymax):
        self.mymin=mymin
        self.mymax=mymax
        self.current=None

    def __getattr__(self, item):
            print("akhjhd")
            self.__dict__[item]=0
            return 0

    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        print("this is called first")
        if item.startswith('cur'):
            print("this raised an error")
            raise AttributeError
        print("This will execute as well")
        return object.__getattribute__(self,item)


obj1 = Count(1,10)
print(obj1.mymin)
print(obj1.mymax)
print(obj1.current)
```

Console Output:

```
this is called first
This will execute as well
1
this is called first
This will execute as well
10
this is called first
this raised an error
akhjhd
this is called first
This will execute as well
0
```

Comment: `getattr` is called because `getattribute` raises `AttributeError`

Comment: agreed, but again __ getattribute__ called, how come?

Comment: Because `self.__dict__` invokes it the second time

Comment: I added an answer with an example

Comment: oic......thanks DeepSpace

Comment: Consult with [Data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) it answers cleary on your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `getattr` is called because `getattribute` raises `AttributeError`
- `self.__dict__` invokes the "second" call to `getattribute`

Clean the code and add `print(item)` to make this clearer:

```
class Count(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.current = None

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        print("in getattr")
        self.__dict__[item] = 0
        return 0

    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        print(item)
        print("in __getattribute__ 1")
        if item.startswith('cur'):
            print("starts with 'cur'")
            raise AttributeError
        print("in __getattribute__ 2")
        return object.__getattribute__(self, item)


obj1 = Count()
print(obj1.current)
```

Outputs

```
current
in __getattribute__ 1
starts with 'cur'
in getattr
__dict__
in __getattribute__ 1
in __getattribute__ 2
0
```

Comment: If I don't have __getattr__ method and return in __getattribute__, why first print in __getattribute__ gets printed again and again (mean recursion of __getattribute__)......How that is getting called more than once?

Comment: @Pravin I can't reproduce this behavior. If I comment out `getattr` then the `AttributeError` from `getattribute` propagates.

Answer (score 0):

You need to consult with python [Data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html)

Excerpts for [`__getattribute__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__):

> Called unconditionally to implement attribute accesses for instances of the class. If the class also defines `__getattr__()`, the latter will not be called unless `__getattribute__()` either calls it explicitly or raises an `AttributeError`.

I see in your code:

```
if item.startswith('cur'):
    print("this raised an error")
    raise AttributeError
```

So I think you did it intentionally